# How to generate a 3D joint probability distribution for bivariate data (e.g., plotly)?

Tags: r, plotly, kernel-density, histogram2d

I have generated these data:

```
dat = MASS::mvrnorm(n = 50, 
                mu = c(1, 5),
                Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), nrow = 2),
                empirical = TRUE)
```

I can generate a 2D histogram with the following code:

```
plot_ly(x = dat[,1], y = dat[,2], type = "histogram2dcontour")
```

[image]

How can I generate a plot of these same data in 3D - either as a 3D histogram or 3D kernel density distribution?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `bivariate`? First, assuming you have two columns - `x` and `y`

```
library(bivariate)
colnames(dat) <- c("x", "y")
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
f = kbvpdf (dat$x, dat$y, 0.7, 7)
plot (f, TRUE, xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

[image]

Another option would be:

```
# install.packages("plot3D")
library(plot3D)
##  Calculate joint counts at cut levels:
z <- table(dat$x, dat$y)

##  Plot as a 3D histogram:
hist3D(z=z, border="black")
```

[image]

Or as 2d heatmap:

```
##  Plot as a 2D heatmap:
image2D(z=z, border="black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using kde2d from MASS and plotly

```
dens2d <- kde2d(dat[,1],dat[,2])

fig <- plot_ly(x=dat[,1], y=dat[,2], z=dens2d$z) 

fig <- fig %>% add_surface()
```